# View last successful mail check/sync

Tags: email, htc-evo-3d

Is it possible to view the last successful sync of my IMAP and Exchange accounts in the Mail app of an HTC Evo 3D?
I just switched from an iPhone 4 and there it said in the bottom of the mail app when that account was last synchronized.
For me it is quite important, because at work the signal is so weak that the sync often fails. When I am waiting for an important mail it is good to know when the mail accounts were last updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can view a log of some kind in the ui, however you can always manually sync and the icons show if it was successful.

```
Settings > Accounts & sync > Manage accounts > your account > OPTION BUTTON > Sync Now
```

- this is in android gingerbread version

You will see the spinning icons appear then disappear when synced, then you know :)

I think I remember seeing widgets that sync your accounts in one click so it may be worth exploring the app markets.

Comment: Most ROM's also display the date and time of the last sync for each selection in this menu. Also a sync icon with an exclamation mark if there was an error.